# Write a query to display the list of order_ids and against it the next order placed by the same customer

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
FIELD        Type
Order_id     bigint
Customer_id  bigint
order_date timestamp
```

Sample Input

```
order_id    Customer_id  Order_date
1           1            2017-11-01
2           2            2017-11-02
3           1            2017-11-03
4           2            2017-11-04
```

Sample Output

```
order_id      next_order_id
1             3
2             4
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks apomene for editing the question in a reaadable manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `LEAD` function .

```
SELECT order_id
    ,LEAD(order_id) OVER (
        PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY ORDER_DATE
        ) as next_order_id
FROM t
ORDER BY order_id;
```

**Demo** : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7d8ab/4

Comment: @AbhishekGupta : Yes, but i recommend you to use LEAD even-though you find it a bit confusing/awkward than conventional joins. Read my post here :  http://qr.ae/TUT1dA